# Wordpress theme is taking no affect?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i want to make some changes into my wordpress css file. i downloaded the style.css and other css file via ftp and made all the changes into the codes i wanted to. I uploaded the files and replace it with the other files. I waited for some time to take it affect but nothing happened, i left it and open my site the other day but the things were still same, no changes. I was using the WP Minify cache plugin. I even deleted it and re upload the css files again but still no changes. I tried out so many things but no success.
I than changed the name of the theme main directory via ftp, it help me a bit and made me happy for awhile, all the changes appeared. I again needed some changes in css files but unfortunately again suffering the same process. Please help :(

P.S. No theme is taking the effects of modifications in the css files codes. i tried different themes, but same results. Even if i delete the style.css nothing happened, but when i delete the entire directory of that theme then blank white page appear on my website.

Comment: Have you opened the css file to see if the modifications are there? Try clearing the browser's cache.

Comment: I did everything, i opened the files, modifications was there. I even clear the browsers cache and cookies. Am at my wits end now. Please Help

Comment: There are very few hosting providers (but a couple) who cache uploaded files for a certain amount of time.  Could this be the problem?  Also, do your edits show up if you view the file after it is uploaded to the web?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you activated the new theme from your administration panel.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Themes#Selecting_the_Active_Theme

Comment: the theme is activated xiwcx... am not a beginner on wordpress :(

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to make sure since there was no mention of it. I hope I didn't insult you! Does clearing the cache in the browser help?Is there any variation across browsers?

Answer (score 0):

When using any cache plugins you should delete its cache when you do any changes to the website. Have you already done that?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other css files being loaded after style.css that may alter what you are trying to change?

It's generally not a good idea to edit the themes style.css directly b/c when you upgrade that theme you will lose all of your customizations.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your theme have some place for custom CSS?  Some themes have it in Appearance >> Theme Options, or something of that nature.  What theme is it?  Do you have a framework, or child themes?  More info needed ... but every theme has a spot for custom css; as was mentioned, it's not best practice to make your modifications in the actual main theme stylesheet, due to updates, etc. ... and anything in the custom css section overrides the default theme stylesheet.